# Split Payment supporting APIs

Tags: web-development, api, online-payment, web-apis

I need a help in finding the best solution for a Payment Gateway.
I need to split the payment so that the payment can be divided between Seller, Website provider and the Payment Gateway provider. Also, it needs to customizable. Is there any payment Gateway that satisfies this scenario? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe offers the requested functionality.  You should explore the Stripe Connect option. It is a customizable solution, and Connect lets you handle complex money movements.  ZiftPay also allows for split payments, distributing vendor payouts, managing money flow, and it has powerful APIs. I think there are more solutions in the market that you could consider.